# Closing windows of tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter, raspberry-pi3

I am new to tkinter and would like to do a UI based on the flags shown.
Basically, i would like to close one windows and open another window with the present state or delete the text and show another text with the present state.

```
class App(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()

    def callback(self):
        self.root.quit()

    def run(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.callback)

        label = tk.Label(self.root, text="Start Initialization")
        label.pack()

        self.root.mainloop()


class QQQ:

    def quit(self):
        self.delete(1.0,END)



class Appo(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()

    def callback(self):
        self.root.quit()

    def run(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.callback)

        label = tk.Label(self.root, text="Initialization ended")
        label.pack()

        self.root.mainloop()


for i in range(100000):

    time.sleep(0.5)

    print(i)

    if(i==1):

        app = App()

        time.sleep(1)

        qqq=QQQ()

    if(i==10):

        app=Appo()
```

Comment: What is your problem/question? (Suggestion, remove double spacing of code.)

Comment: In the thread function, you can use a while loop and check for a condition which you can change in the main thread.

Comment: I am thinking of changing the text messages real time.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is change the text of the label, then use the `config` method on the label. The `App`, `Appo`, and `QQQ` classes, as well as the `for` loop can be combined into a single class as:

```
import Tkinter as tk #Python 2
#import tkinter as tk #Python 3
import threading
import time


class App(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.start()

    def callback(self):
        self.root.quit()

    def run(self):
        self.root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.callback)

        label = tk.Label(self.root, text="Initial Text") # You can use text=""
        label.pack()

        for i in range(100000):
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print (i)
            if i == 1:
                label.config(text="Start Initialization")
                time.sleep(1)
                label.config(text="")
            if i == 10:
                label.config(text="Initialization ended")
        #self.root.mainloop()

app = App()
app.root.mainloop()
```

It might be better to use the `after` method of tkinter for time delays instead of `time.sleep()`